# PHP preg_match() steam link validation error

Tags: php, ajax, regex

What's wrong with this `preg_match()` usage? I want to check steam lobby link and if it's matching then write to database. If not, just echo the error. I am doing this through ajax. Is it better to do this with ajax or `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`?

```
<?php
require("../includes/config.php");
$lobby = "steam://joinlobby/730/109775243427128868/76561198254260308";
if (!preg_match("%^((steam?:)+(/joinlobby\/730\/)+([0-9]{17,25}\/.?)+([0-9]{17,25})/$)%i", $lobby)) {
    echo "Lobby link isn't formatted correctly.";
}
else {
    $rank = "Golden";
    $mic = "No";
    try {
       $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO created_lobby (lobby_link, current_rank, have_mic) VALUES (:lobby_link, '$rank', '$mic')");
       $stmt->execute(array(
       ':input_link' => $_POST['lobbyLink']
       ));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

**My Problem:**
When I execute this code, it will give me false.

Thank you for help.

Comment: So exactly HOW is this code not working?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add this. Now it's in description

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` if you're using `%` as the regexp delimiter.

Comment: The regexp matches `/joinlobby`, but the URL has `//joinlobby`.

Comment: Why do you have `+` after `(steam?:)`? Can you really have more than 1 `steam:` at the beginning of the URL, e.g. `steam:steam:steam:`?

Comment: Considering @Barmar comment, then   `+(//joinlobby/730/)+([0-9]{17,25}/.?)+([0-9]{17,25})/$ `

Comment: Use `^((steam?:)(//joinlobby/730/)+([0-9]{17,25}/.?)+([0-9]{17,25})$)`... You don't need the trailing `/` as your url doesn't include one. Also as Barmar points out, the `+` after `(steam?:)` is quite useless and redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$lobby = "steam://joinlobby/730/109775243427128868/76561198254260308";
if (!preg_match("%^(steam?:)+(//joinlobby/730/)+([0-9]{17,25}/.?)+([0-9]{17,25}$)%i", $lobby)) {
    echo "Lobby link isn't formatted correctly.";
}
```

I changed `/joinlobby` to `//joinlobby`, and remove the `/` at the end. I also removed the unnecessary `()` around everything.

I suspect you also shouldn't have `(...)+` around `steam?:` and `//joinlobby/730/`. They'll cause repeated uses of those prefixes to be accepted as correct, e.g. `steam:steam:...`